# ArgoCD UI too slow for an application with many pods and deploys

Tags: performance, kubernetes, argocd

I set up argo CD for my kubernetes cluster and when I added an application with many deploys and pod, its UI speed became too slow.
I added --enable-gzip to the configs but it is still slow.
How can I fix this?

I added --enable-gzip flag to its configs.

Comment: have you tried to scale up/out your services - https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/high_availability/#scaling-up

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: I am also having this issue when getting to 100s of containers